# Obtener agrupaciones de valores únicos

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy haciendo una petición a un servicio en el que se me devuelve la siguiente información:

```
        {
            "orden": 0,
            "idlinea": 1,
            "idtrayecto": 1,
            "utmy": 4824500,
            "utmx": 281405
        },
        {
            "orden": 1,
            "idlinea": 1,
            "idtrayecto": 1,
            "utmy": 4824470,
            "utmx": 281416
        },
        {
            "orden": 2,
            "idlinea": 1,
            "idtrayecto": 2,
            "utmy": 4824481,
            "utmx": 281495
        },
        {
            "orden": 3,
            "idlinea": 1,
            "idtrayecto": 2,
            "utmy": 4824487,
            "utmx": 281540
        }
        ...
```

Y esto va en aumento hasta acabarse todas las líneas con sus respectivos trayectos.

Me gustaría agrupar el contenido, de tal madera que para la línea 1, trayecto 1, obtenga todo el grupo de coordenadas. Y asi sucesivamente.

De momento he obtenido los valores únicos de las líneas y los trayectos así:

```
    let distinctValues = []

      let infoRoute = {
        line: null,
        journey: null,
        coordinates: []
      }
      data.forEach((route) => {
        if (route.idlinea != infoRoute.line || route.idtrayecto != infoRoute.journey) {
          infoRoute.line = route.idlinea;
          infoRoute.journey = route.idtrayecto;
          distinctValues.push([infoRoute.line, infoRoute.journey])
        }
      });
```

Con esto ya consigo : [[1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [2,1]...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías intentar con un hashmap donde la nombre del valor del array está compuesto por el idlinea y idtrayecto.

```
const rutas = [Array]
const mapped = []
for (rutas in ruta) {
  const identificador = `${ruta.idlinea}.${ruta.idtrayecto}`
  if (!mapped[identificador]) {
    mapped[identificador] = []
  }
  mapped[identificador] = ruta
}
```

Para obtener cualquier ruta solo es necesario llamar `mapped[idruta + '.' + idtrayecto]`.