# Valores únicos en un JSON decodificado en PHP

Tags: php, json, jsonobject, jsonarray

Haciendo un poco que arqueología me he encontrado con esta pregunta:
[filtrar-array-de-objectos-en-php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/262289) Como no he sido capaz de dar con la solución, la lanzo de nuevo aportando las pruebas que he hecho.

En primer lugar el dataset:

```
<?php

$a=json_decode('[
    {
        "cupon":1,
        "fecha":"2019-09-12"
    },
    {
        "cupon":1,
        "fecha":"2019-09-12"
    },
    {
        "cupon":2,
        "fecha":"2019-09-14"
    },
    {
        "cupon":2,
        "fecha":"2019-09-19"
    },  
    {
        "cupon":3,
        "fecha":"2019-09-19"
    }
]');
```

Mi intento de convertir el objeto en array:

```
foreach($a as $i=>$b)
    foreach($b as $j=>$c)
        $d[$i][$j]=$c;
```

Y mi intento que eliminar duplicados:

```
$d=array_unique($d);
```

Visualización del resultado:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($d);
echo '</pre>';
```

Y los errores que me he encontrado:

> Notice: Array to string conversion on line 27

Visualizando únicamente el primer elemento, en vez de:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cupon] => 1
            [fecha] => 2019-09-12
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cupon] => 2
            [fecha] => 2019-09-14
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [cupon] => 2
            [fecha] => 2019-09-19
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [cupon] => 3
            [fecha] => 2019-09-19
        )

)
```

¿Hay alguna función que convierta de objetos a arrays directamente, ahorrándome esos bucles? ¿Hay algún equivalente al `array_unique` para subarrays? ¿O no queda otra que hacer una especie de índice compuesto como el que sugieren en la pregunta [obtener-agrupaciones-de-valores-únicos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/274750/)?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php#116302

Comment: Gracias @alanfcm, aunque no es exactamente con uno de los índices, sino con el subarray completo, es decir, que ambos datos coincidan...

Answer (score 2):

¡Ojo! Se que seguramente no sea la solución mas óptima pero yo procedería así:

- Convierto a *array* (así me fue mas fácil resolverlo)
- Declaro un vector vacío que luego llenare
- Recorro con un `foreach` el vector transformado y hago un `push` al vector vacío declarado
- Imprimo por fuera el vector pasandolo por el método `array_unique`

Código:

```
$a= ('[
    {
        "cupon":1,
        "fecha":"2019-09-12"
    },
    {
        "cupon":1,
        "fecha":"2019-09-12"
    },
    {
        "cupon":2,
        "fecha":"2019-09-14"
    },
    {
        "cupon":3,
        "fecha":"2019-09-19"
    }
]');

$nuevoData = json_decode($a, true);

$vector = [];
foreach($nuevoData as $renglon1) {
    array_push($vector, $renglon1["cupon"], $renglon1["fecha"]);   
}

print_r(array_unique($vector));
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2019-09-12
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 2019-09-14
    [6] => 3
    [7] => 2019-09-19
)
```

Comment: Pero se te han juntado los elementos, ¿no? La idea es que un elemento como el 2 / 2019-09-19 se considere diferente a los demás... También ya tenemos ganas de complicarnos la vida con PHP, con lo fácil que es un `SELECT DISTINCT` en SQL :)

Comment: No entiendo el punto de que se juntan los elementos, igual si me lo explicas mejor te puedo responder. Saludos y si tienes razón con lo simple que sería SQL

Comment: Que ya no tienes un array con un array indpendiente para cada pareja cupon/fecha, sino un array enumerado muy largo.

Comment: Ahh ok dame un momento

Comment: Ya está el dataset ampliado con el elemento que debería considerar diferente

Comment: Ya comprendí tu punto, si logro concretar una respuesta actualizaré la axistente

Comment: Tampoco te agobies, era simple curiosidad, no estoy con nada que dependa de esto. Aunque me alegra que tampoco fuera una trivialidad :) Gracias por intentarlo

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes un objeto en notacion JSON lo puedes pasar a un `array` de la siguiente manera

Desde la documentacion de PHP
https://devdocs.io/php/function.json-decode

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

?>
```

Y el efecto inverso
Tambien desde la documentacion
https://devdocs.io/php/function.json-encode

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?> 

//Salida
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

Luego puedes usar `array_unique` sobre tu objeto convertido a `array`.
Ejemplo desde la documentacion de PHP
https://devdocs.io/php/function.array-unique

```
<?php
$input = array("a" => "verde", "rojo", "b" => "verde", "azul", "rojo");
$result = array_unique($input);
print_r($result);
?> 

//SALIDA
Array
(
    [a] => verde
    [0] => rojo
    [1] => azul
)
```

Comment: A la primera pregunta me has respondido perfecto: era el `true` de `json_decode()` ¡Muchas gracias! Pero el `array_unique()` no funciona con arrays dentro de elementos del array :( Da el Notice que comento en la pregunta

Comment: En la documentacion esta que `array_unique` no funciona en arreglos multidimensionales. Eso tendras que construirlo tu. Si lo que quieres es Recorrer `A` que es un arreglo que contiene a los arreglos `B`, `C` y `D` y estos tienen indices coincidentes, te vas a derretir el cerebro. De antemano te digo que hay funciones de PHP que te ayudan a solventar el problemas pero la mayor parte la haces tu. Si lo que quieres es limpiar sencillamente `A[ B[ ] ]` puedes usar `array_unique` sobre cada matriz de `A`

Comment: Pues no puedo dejar de darte la razón, seguro que ese JSON viene de un MongoDB o de alguna base de datos relacional que con un simple DISTINCT hubiera resuelto el problema... Si es que a veces nos empeñamos en clavar tornillos a martillazos...